# Sorting NSDictionary by fields with same keys

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have `NSArray` of  `NSDictionaries`, in which *each* dictionary can look like this:

```
value: dog for key subject
value: bird for key subject
value: something for key subject
value: fly for key subject
value: something for key subject
value: fly for key subject
value: bird for key subject
```

Where all of them have the same keys(=`subject`), but the values could be different , and they are **`unknown`* before-head.
I need to take this array , run on it , and get a list of keys with the same values, and count how many i have in each one, for example :

respond:

```
1 dog
2 fly
2 bird
2 something
```

Where i didn't know before, what the possible values(or names) that i can have .

So, i could just loop on the array , than check what the subjects are for each dictionary, than create a new field for each new name,and start to count for him,than add new field(name) when i have.
This sounds like an awful thing to do, i am sure there are other ways ..

Comment: NSDictionaries allows only unique keys its not possible to have same keys in Dictionaries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess it could be solved in many ways. Here is one:

```
// The given array
NSArray *array = @[
@{@"subject": @"dog"},
@{@"subject": @"fly"},
@{@"subject": @"fly"},
@{@"subject": @"bird"},
@{@"subject": @"bird"},
@{@"subject": @"something"},
@{@"subject": @"something"}];

// Extract all values for 'subject' key of each dictionary
NSArray *values = [array valueForKeyPath:@"subject"];

// Create a counted set with those values
NSCountedSet *cset = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:values];
```

At this point if you log `cset` the output will be:

```
<NSCountedSet: 0x7fc6e0c0a4e0> (something [2], dog [1], fly [2], bird [2])
```

We're getting close!

```
// Enumerate each string and access its count
for (NSString *value in [cset allObjects]) {
    NSLog(@"%@ %@", @([cset countForObject:value]), value);
}
```

Finally if you'd like to get a sorted array based on the count of each value, you could do something like this:

```
// This will sort from highest counts to lower ones.
// Exchange obj1 with obj2 to reverse the sorting
NSArray *sortedValues = [[cset allObjects] sortedArrayUsingComparator: ^(id obj1, id obj2) {
    return [@([cset countForObject:obj2]) compare:@([cset countForObject:obj1])];
}];
```

Comment: I did come up with the same solution but 5 mins late. +1 :)

Comment: actually i had a mistake in the question , the main array has dictionaries, in each dictionary i have only one value for the key "subject" , i have to go on all keys named "subject" in the main array, and count how many i have for every unknown group .. (?)

Comment: @Curnelious You're welcome! If you think though that your 'real' problem is not solved by this answer then I guess you could open another question (or maybe edit this one(?))

Comment: no, because you can't have same keys in the same dictionary anyway, so my question's example should be point on values in DIFFERENT dictionaries and not the same one, and your answer is answering just that.

Comment: @Alladinian wow just now i get to see how beautiful your answer was! wish i could vote twice for you ! :)

Comment: the last part of the code(sorting) has an error, it says you can't do that on the cset .

Comment: @Curnelious You're right it was a warning. Fixed now, thanks for the heads up and your kind words :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for neater and a magical way, Create a category on NSArray and implement a custom key path operator,

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSArray (customKVCOperator)

- (id)_countUniqueObjectsForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath;

@end
```

The implementation would be,

```
#import "NSArray+customKVCOperator.h"

@implementation NSArray (customKVCOperator)

- (id)_countUniqueObjectsForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath
{

    NSArray *distinctObjects = [self valueForKeyPath:keyPath];
    NSCountedSet* countedSet = [[NSCountedSet alloc] initWithArray:distinctObjects];
    NSMutableArray *testArray = [@[] mutableCopy];
    for (NSString* val in countedSet) {
        [testArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ = %lu", val, (unsigned long)[countedSet countForObject:val]]];
         }
    return testArray;
}

@end
```

Then a one liner would do for the filtering like below. (Make sure to import your category)

```
   NSArray *test = @[@{@"Subject":@"dog"},
      @{@"Subject":@"dog"},
      @{@"Subject":@"cat"},
      @{@"Subject":@"dog"},
      @{@"Subject":@"monkey"},
      @{@"Subject":@"dog"},
      @{@"Subject":@"cat"}
      ];
    NSLog(@"%@",[test valueForKeyPath:@"@countUniqueObjects.Subject"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

value: dog for key subject
value: bird for key subject
value: something for key subject
value: fly for key subject
value: something for key subject
value: fly for key subject
value: bird for key subject

```
NSMutableArray *arrSorted = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[[NSSet setWithArray:[NSArray arrayWithArray:[YourArray valueForKey:@"subject"]]] allObjects]];
```

This code will output

```
dog
fly
bird
something
```